# How do you set which window an mg is initially set up in when you garrison a building?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I realise they move about as required but how do you set which window an mg is initially set up in when you garrison a building or bunker?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played CoH, but I seem to remember that when MGs are garrisoned, you force them to fire in the direction you want, and they'll set up that way. This isn't perfect/ideal, since you have to wait for them to garrison and then issue the command, but it's better than waiting for the enemy to arrive.

Come to think of it, I *may* be thinking of a different game though. Apologies in advance if this is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a way to get them to start in any direction, and am not sure it's possible.

The intuitive way to do this, were it possible, to me would be to hold the mouse button after clicking to garrison, and try dragging out in the direction to cover like you normally do.